# Four Minim at the time of the Great Revolt

Tags: history, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

This is a [5 Agorot coin](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_(%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2)#%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_(1985_-_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D)_-_100_%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C_%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9) bearing a copy of a coin from the 4th year of the Great Revolt (70AD) that pictures the 4 Minim:

[image]

I can spot two oddities relative to what's commonly accepted: there are two Etrogim and Hadasim are full of berries.

Why is it so?

Comment: I don't know why they chose that coin to copy.  Maybe they used myrtle branches with the berries then--sure looks like it.  Bar Kochba's four species look more accurate to our modern eyes-no berries and one etrog.

Comment: Maybe berries were a sign of fruitfulness-even the letters seem to have them. And they put one on the bottom of each etrog, just for good measure.

Comment: How do you know the little balls are _hadas_ berries and not dates?

Comment: @WAF I don't. Since the common opinion is that the coin pictures the 4 minim and not something else, the balls belong seemingly to Hadas. Feel free to offer your explanation.

Comment: Isn't it ok if there are some berries as long as it's mostly leaves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of the other coins minted during the revolt and siege of the 1st century, it is not surprising that the depiction of the species is less photographic of "full sets" and more representative of the *mitzva* and of the holiday. The symbol may have been an act of rebellion in itself, bringing distinctly Jewish practice, whose restoration they were trying to achieve, to the fore. This would be in keeping with the Jewish patriotic slogans adorning these same coins.

For other examples of the symbolic 4 species images on these coins, see [this survey](https://www.academia.edu/2306383/Jewish_Coins_of_the_Two_Wars_Aims_and_Meaning) of the coins of that period and their meanings, particularly

- 2 *lulavim* (bundles?) and an *esrog* (p. 130)
- a palm tree (p. 130)
- 2 *lulavim* (bundles?) alone (p. 130)
- a lone *esrog* (p. 130)
- a *lulav* bundle and an *esrog* (p. 134)
- a *lulav* (bundle?) and 2 *esrogim* (p. 136)
- a *lulav* bundle and and *esrog* (p. 138)
- a lone *lulav* (p. 138)
- a *nisuch hamayim* jug and *arava* (p. 139)

Comment: Very impressive and informative. Thank you.